# Magento 2 Change custom option name with mySql

Tags: magento2, database, configurable-product, custom

I have this line which I can use to update the price of a custom product option.

```
 UPDATE `catalog_product_option_type_title` a JOIN `catalog_product_option_type_price` b ON a.option_type_id = b.option_type_id SET b.price = 3.99 WHERE a.title = 'Soft Style Unisex T-shirt'
```

I am trying to change it so that I can change the name of the option now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out running this in mysql

```
 UPDATE `catalog_product_option_type_title` a JOIN `catalog_product_option_type_title` b ON a.option_type_id = b.option_type_id SET b.title = 'Big-Dimmable' WHERE a.title = 'little-dimmable'
```